# Delete row if cell in a column is blank VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code to delete a row if a cell in column A is blank:

```
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
```

The problem is, if the column doesn't have any blank cells the macro returns an error. Is there a way to mitigate this problem?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next`, `Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`, `On Error GoTo 0`.

Comment: Or, `On Error Resume Next`, `Dim rng As Range`, `Set rng = Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`, `On Error GoTo 0`, `If Not rng Is Nothing Then`, `rng.EntireRow.Delete`, `End If`.